# How to show validator error messages to user when validation error occures?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have the followinf scenario:

1. I have field with DoubleRangeValidator with error message specified
   field.addValidator(new DoubleRangeValidator("Salary must be a numeric value.",0d,1000000d));
2. Under SAVE button I call BeanFieldGroup.commit() which raises exception on non numeric value in such field
3. To show errors I'm using ErrorUtils class mentioned here
   [Display error messages directly in Vaadin 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020499/display-error-messages-directly-in-vaadin-7)

.. which simply calls component.getErrorMessage() for all fields / components and gather all error messages. But the field with DoubleRange validator returns null for getErrorMessage() so no error message is available here. The same apply  for other validators. So my question is how can I show validator error messages when validation error occures during the commit() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your error with the `ErrorUtils` class you mentioned but the `getErrorMessage` method did not returned `null`. Maybe something is wrong with how you create your `BeanFieldGroup` and/or `Field`. Here's my code:

```java
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    BeanFieldGroup<MyBean> bfg = new BeanFieldGroup<>(MyBean.class);
    bfg.setItemDataSource(new MyBean());

    Field<?> salaryField = bfg.buildAndBind("salary");
    salaryField.addValidator(new DoubleRangeValidator("Salary must be a numeric value.", 0d, 1000000d));

    Button commit = new Button("Save", e -> {
        try {
            bfg.commit();
        }
        catch (CommitException ce) {
            ErrorUtils.showComponentErrors(bfg.getFields());
        }
    });

    VerticalLayout hLayout = new VerticalLayout(salaryField, commit);
    setContent(hLayout);
}
```

```java
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private double salary;

    public MyBean() {}

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out that I had field.setValidationVisible(false); ... and it caused the validation message to be unavailable. Settings it to true makes the error message available. But now it shows default message  'Could not convert value to Double' instead of my custom text.

Comment: Yes, before validating (i.e. going through `DoubleRangeValidator`) the salary value, Vaadin must first convert it to the property's type (i.e. `double`) and this is where the new error comes from. If you want to override this, use `field.setConverter()`. There's an example here: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3625631.